# highcharts build map with a set of values and display another set of values as labels

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have a set of data like this :

```
var data = [
    ['gl', 2584],
    ['sh', 100201],
    ['bu', 2025],
    ['lk', 30336],
    ['as', 41225],
    ['dk', 500],
    ['fo', 655225],
    ['gu', 7555],
    ['mp', 85454],
    ['um', 90147],
    ['us', 10087]]
```

I am normalizing the above array into the range of `[0,1]` to give different colours to High charts world map based on following conditions.

```
0.0-0.15 Green
0.15-0.30 yellow
0.30-0.60 orange
0.60-1 red
```

I want to set colours based on normalized array but show the labels from above `data` array. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of stops value with each color. Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gbnd36zr/

```
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    stops: [
      [0.15, 'green'],
      [0.3, 'yellow'],
      [0.6, 'orange'],
      [1, 'red']
    ]
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.stops